# "to pitch someone" on something

Tags: verbs

Reading this [**article**](https://www.yahoo.com/huffpost/democrats-covid-19-vaccine-patents-waiver-letter-biden-122419232.html), there is a line saying,

> The letter, drafted by Democratic Reps. Jan Schakowsky (Ill.), Rosa DeLauro (Conn.) and Earl Blumenauer (Ore.) with the support of 107 other colleagues, **pitches Biden** on the opportunity to save lives as well as improve the United States’ global image, battered during the Donald Trump administration.

There are many definitions from my dictionary.

So can someone help me to understand this verb? Pursuade? may be?

Thank you.

Comment: [(informal) to approach or court (as a person, company, or the public) in hope of a sale, approval, or interest; make an appeal to](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pitch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "persuade or promote". But the use here seems unorthodox.

Typically the object of the verb is the concept that you are trying to suggest.

> She pitched her idea to me over a business lunch.

The standard form would be

> ... pitches the opportunity to save lives as well as improve the United States’ global image, battered during the Donald Trump administration, to Biden.

But the very long phrase "opportunity....administration" makes that hard to parse.  So a different structure has been used.  However I'd never seen "pitch" used like this, but

> She pitched me on her idea over a business lunch.

is understandable, and I can find some real use of this:

> So, when I met Brian in-person in New York and *he pitched me on his idea* to bring similar Ride Home podcasts to more verticals, it didn’t take long to close me as his first investor. [source](https://awilkinson.medium.com/the-daily-podcast-revolution-80a10f2cad50)